# Creating a filtering function using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hey all here is my issue, I am using a SQL query to try to return results based on a post's meta data. This meta data is input by the user during the post creation within the user interface. I am having an issue with the filter, its working well for just one variable at a time but no more than that (ex: if topic is selected it works fine, however if topic AND media is selected it will return no results) here is the code:

```
$db_build_post_filter_WHERE = array();
// Default to avoid errors on WHERE GROUP BY
$db_build_post_filter_WHERE [] = 'cmsp_post.post_id > 0';
//$db_build_post_filter_WHERE [] = 'cmsp_post.post_id = cmsp_post_meta.post_id';
if ( isset( $gnocore_cmsp_build_topic_slug_id_array[$filter_topic] ) ) {
    $db_build_post_filter_WHERE [] = 'post_meta_key = "topic_id" AND post_meta_value = ' . $gnocore_cmsp_build_topic_slug_id_array[$filter_topic];
}
if ( isset( $gnocore_cmsp_build_media_slug_id_array[$filter_media] ) ) {
$db_build_post_filter_WHERE [] = 'post_meta_key = "media_id" AND post_meta_value = ' . $gnocore_cmsp_build_media_slug_id_array[$filter_media];
}
if ( isset( $gnocore_cmsp_build_author_slug_id_array[$filter_author] ) ) {
$db_build_post_filter_WHERE [] = 'post_meta_key = "author_id" AND post_meta_value = ' . $gnocore_cmsp_build_author_slug_id_array[$filter_author];
}   

// PROJECT FILTER ARRAY 
$build_post_filter_array = array();
gnoshare_db_select ('cmsp_post LEFT JOIN cmsp_post_meta ON cmsp_post.post_id = cmsp_post_meta.post_id','cmsp_post.post_id',implode(' AND ',$db_build_post_filter_WHERE) . ' GROUP BY cmsp_post.post_id','cmsp_post.project_id, post_name, cmsp_post.post_id','db_build_post_filter_array_num','db_build_post_filter_array_results');
if ( $db_build_post_filter_array_num > 0 ) {
    foreach ($db_build_post_filter_array_results as $db_build_post_filter_array_result) {
        $build_post_filter_array [$db_build_post_filter_array_result->post_id] = '';
    }
}
```

I believe my issue is in the "PROJECT FILTER ARRAY" portion, if anyone could assist it would be much appreciated.

Cheers

**EDIT**: Changing the ' AND ' to ' OR ' generates a result of simply displaying all posts, I think it is fair to say my issue lies in this line of code, however I still can not find a way to generate the result I'm looking for.

```
gnoshare_db_select ('cmsp_post LEFT JOIN cmsp_post_meta ON cmsp_post.post_id = cmsp_post_meta.post_id','cmsp_post.post_id',implode(' OR ',$db_build_post_filter_WHERE) . ' GROUP BY cmsp_post.post_id','cmsp_post.project_id, post_name, cmsp_post.post_id','db_build_post_filter_array_num','db_build_post_filter_array_results');
```

**EDIT**: here is my table (roughly):

```
+----------+---------------+-----------------+  
| post_id  | post_meta_key | post_meta_value |  
+----------+---------------+-----------------+  
|     1    |   topic_id    |        1        |  
+----------+---------------+-----------------+  
|     1    |   media_id    |        1        |  
+----------+---------------+-----------------+  
|     1    |   author_id   |        2        |  
+----------+---------------+-----------------+  
|     2    |   media_id    |        2        |  
+----------+---------------+-----------------+  
|     2    |   topic_id    |        2        |  
+----------+---------------+-----------------+
```

and I want it to filter based on the selections the user has made for the post (ex: user selected topic 1, media 1 and author 2 for post 1 and media 2 and topic 2 for post 2 *shown in table above*) given that this example is true, I want my webpage to generate post one if any of the following is selected by the filter: filter by topic 1 would show post one only, filter by topic 1 and media 1 would show post 1 only, filter by topic 1 media 2 would show a message stating that there is no matches to the selected criteria, and so on. does this clarify a little more?

Comment: Is there a way with this gnoshare_db_select() function to print the final query that is being used?

Comment: [query] => SELECT cmsp_post.post_id FROM cmsp_post LEFT JOIN cmsp_post_meta ON cmsp_post.post_id = cmsp_post_meta.post_id WHERE cmsp_post.post_id > 0 AND post_meta_key = "topic_id" AND post_meta_value = 1 GROUP BY cmsp_post.post_id ORDER BY cmsp_post.project_id, post_name, cmsp_post.post_id [return_val]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, you should use OR between filters and enclose them with (). Something like:

```
 $db_build_post_filter_WHERE [] = '(cmsp_post.post_id > 0)';
 if ( isset( $gnocore_cmsp_build_topic_slug_id_array[$filter_topic] ) ) {
   $db_build_post_filter_WHERE [] = '(post_meta_key = "topic_id" 
                                     AND post_meta_value = ' . 
                $gnocore_cmsp_build_topic_slug_id_array[$filter_topic].')';
 }
 if ( isset( $gnocore_cmsp_build_media_slug_id_array[$filter_media] ) ) {
   $db_build_post_filter_WHERE [] = '(post_meta_key = "media_id" 
                                    AND post_meta_value = ' . 
               $gnocore_cmsp_build_media_slug_id_array[$filter_media].')';
 }
 //Other conditions

// PROJECT FILTER ARRAY 
$build_post_filter_array = array();
gnoare_db_select ('cmsp_post 
                   LEFT JOIN cmsp_post_meta
                          ON cmsp_post.post_id = cmsp_post_meta.post_id',
                 'cmsp_post_post.post_id',
                 implode(' OR ',$db_build_post_filter_WHERE) . 
                ' GROUP BY cmsp_post.post_id','cmsp_post.project_id, post_name, cmsp_post.post_id','db_build_post_filter_array_num','db_build_post_filter_array_results');
```

Comment: here is was what given after applying the above coding `Array
(
    [query] => SELECT cmsp_post_post.post_id FROM cmsp_post 
                   LEFT JOIN cmsp_post_meta
                          ON cmsp_post.post_id = cmsp_post_meta.post_id WHERE cmsp_post.post_id > 0 OR (post_meta_key = "topic_id" AND post_meta_value = 1) GROUP BY cmsp_post.post_id ORDER BY cmsp_post.project_id, post_name, cmsp_post.post_id
    [return_val] => 0
    [cache] => 
    [str] => Unknown column 'cmsp_post_post.post_id' in 'field list'
    [is_insert] => 1
)`

Comment: I think you have a misspelling. See the error given, it says cms_post_post.post_id, not cms_post.post_id. Could you confirm the names, please?

Comment: I corrected the duplicate _post, however the issue still remains of the results not being returned properly. I'll add a quick mock up of the SQL table I'm using for visual